# Setting img to div size

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set an image height and width to the size of the `div` it's contained in?
Not just using `background-size: cover`?

Or is this a stupid question and that's the only way you can do it?

Comment: You mean `width:100%;height:100%` ?

Comment: Always try to show your work, what you've tried, and why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `width:100%;` and `height:100%` on the img tag.

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kf1tmu5s/

Answer (score 1):

Setting the width and height of your image to 100% would stretch the imgage, depending on the size of your parent div.

you could use object-fit

here is an example:

```
.cover{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmaLbvLt/18/

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your div a class name.
2. Set image size to size of div.

```css
.image_containing img{
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image_containing">
<img src="xxx.yy">
</div>
```